# Django development server unreachable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web-applications, server

I run django on my windows 7 machine without virtual environment. After typing - "python manage.py runserver" it shows me that development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000 but whenever I try to access it shows me an error like - "This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 took too long to respond."

I also tried on different ports like - 8001, 8080 but couldn't get into it.

Comment: Did you include the port in the browser? Can you see the incoming request in the console?

Comment: Yes I tried it too. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Make sure you provided  `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in any of your configuration file or settings

Comment: There is no configuration with localhost @angrysumit

Comment: Try with `python manage.py runserver localhost:8000`

Comment: Also, which browser are you using